# How do I simplify these repetitive make targets?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Consider these targets:

```
test/masterfiles/efl_data/efl_class_cmd_regcmp.json: \
  test/masterfiles/efl_data/efl_class_cmd_regcmp.csv
   $(CSVTOJSON) -b efl_class_cmd_regcmp < $< > $@

test/masterfiles/efl_data/efl_class_returnszero.json: \
  test/masterfiles/efl_data/efl_class_returnszero.csv
   $(CSVTOJSON) -b efl_class_returnszero < $< > $@

test/masterfiles/efl_data/efl_class_expression.json: \
  test/masterfiles/efl_data/efl_class_expression.csv
   $(CSVTOJSON) -b efl_class_expression < $< > $@
```

The pattern efl_class_*some_word* is repeated in the target, the dependency, and the recipe to make the target. What I can I do to reduce these rules to a single rule? Then normal use of `%`, `$@`, and `@<` does not seem to apply.

Comment: You may need to add `.csv` and `.json` to `.SUFFIXES`, probably in that order.  You need to add a rule `.csv.json:` (or the `%.csv%.json` equivalent, which I've probably butchered) plus a command like the one you've used.  You need to use macros for the directory name and probably the file names too.  I don't trust running `make` rules where both the source and target are in remote directories; the `makefile` should normally deal with files in the current directory.  'Tis one reason this is commentary; I'm too lazy to experiment with what's necessary.

Comment: `SUFFIXES` implicit rules won't work if you want to put things in other directories.  You need pattern rules for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write a pattern rule:

```
EFL_PARTS = cmd_regcmp returnszero expression

EFL_DIR = test/masterfiles/efl_data

$(EFL_DIR)/%.json: $(EFL_DIR)/%.csv
        $(CSVTOJSON) -b $* < $< > $@

all: $(patsubst %,$(EFL_DIR)/efl_class_%.json,$(EFL_PARTS))
.PHONY: all
```